# Tag merge / synonym request: [js] → [javascript]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

There are currently 8 questions with the tag [js](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/js), they seem to all refer to JavaScript, so it would seem natural to make this a synonym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done, [js](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/js) is now a synonym of [javascript](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript).